# Legend inside the for loop

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

In the following code it should show legend for each curve (there are 7 curves in each plot) and with specific name as I used `f string` for its name, but legend just shows the name of last curve for all plots.

Any help please?

```
for x in range(len(ng)):
    fig, (ax1) = plt.subplots(1,figsize=(9,6))
    plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.5,hspace=0.1)
    for xx in range(1,819):
            Ju_list=[]
            ET_list=[]
            ET1_list=[]
            Unu_list=[]
            z_list=[]
            uf_list=[]
            for z in np.arange(0,11):
                    Ju = dfimppara.iloc[xx, 1]
                    Jl = dfimppara.iloc[xx, 2]
                    lim = Ju - Jl
                    if lim > 1:
                        pass
                    else:
                        if Ju<8:

                            Ju_list.append(dfimppara.iloc[xx, 1])
                            T = ET(xx, z, ng[x], 1e-24, Tg[x], 1)
                            BC = Bcmb(xx,z)
                            Btex = B(xx,T)
                            ET_list.append(1-BC/Btex)
                            z_list.append(z)              
                            l1,=ax1.plot(z_list, ET_list)

                            ax1.title.set_text(f'UF=1e-24,Tg={Tg[x]},ng={ng[x]}')
                            ax1.set_ylabel('1-BB(CMB)/BB(Tex)')
                            ax1.set_xlabel('z')
                            plt.legend([l1],[f'{dfimppara.iloc[xx, 1]}'])


                        else:
                            pass

    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do in every loop is assign a label to the plot. `pyplot.legend` simply places a legend on the axes, based on the labels. Try this (note the difference in your `ax1.plot` line):

```
                else:
                    if Ju<8:

                        Ju_list.append(dfimppara.iloc[xx, 1])
                        T = ET(xx, z, ng[x], 1e-24, Tg[x], 1)
                        BC = Bcmb(xx,z)
                        Btex = B(xx,T)
                        ET_list.append(1-BC/Btex)
                        z_list.append(z)              
                        l1,=ax1.plot(z_list, ET_list, label=f'{dfimppara.iloc[xx, 1]}')

                        ax1.title.set_text(f'UF=1e-24,Tg={Tg[x]},ng={ng[x]}')
                        ax1.set_ylabel('1-BB(CMB)/BB(Tex)')
                        ax1.set_xlabel('z')
                        plt.legend()

                    else:
                        pass

plt.show()
```

Comment: But unfortunately this doe not works. According to this `if Ju<8:` we have  7 curves and we should have 7 labels in legend, but in this way we have 7 * 10 labels. 10 comes from `for z in np.arange(0,11):`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem, given that the only change is adding the label to the line where you plot the lines. If you have 7 lines, you should get 7 labels. Since I don't have your data and then can't really run the code, is hard for me to look at the code and understand what you want.

Comment: we have just 3 loops and 2 ones inside are important `xx` and `z` by `if Ju<8:` I restrict `xx` loop and just consider 7 sata from that and also for different `z` it will be calculated and the plots is a function versus `z`. So I have 7 curves in my plots but when I do this for legend it will be `1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6  6 6 7 7 7 7 7 7  7 7 7 7` which repeat as much as number of loop of `z` it should be 1 2 3 4 5 6 7